# Java Spring switch service if error

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

I have 2 class implementing the same interface:

```
public interface Service {
      public Boolean process();
    }
```

These 2 class are doing the same thing (function process()) but the second class is here as a backup if the first class function process() doesn't work.

Right now, the way I'm doing it is like this:

```
@Autowired
Service1 myService1;

@Autowired
Service2 myService2;


if (!myService1.process()) {
  // if service1 fail, try with service 2
  if (!myService2.process()) {
    // throw error
  }
}
```

However I would prefer to use conditional or injection to do something like:

```
@Conditional(?)
@Autowired
Service service;
```

and just call service.process() which somehow would try with Service1 first and Service2 then.

Any idea on how to implement something like this with?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to implement the design pattern Chain of Responsibility.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I found this little bit of code that seems to make sense but still wondering if there is any better way of doing it?

 public abstract class Service{
        protected Processor next;
        public void setNextProcessor(Processor p) {
            next = p;
        }
        abstract protected void process();
    }
    public class Service1 extends Service{
       
        protected Boolean process() {
            System.out.println("Run Service1: ");
            if (error) {
                next.process();
            }
        }
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not specifically, but Spring allows you to annotate a `List` of Beans which it would then populate with every defined and annotated implementation of that bean.

```
@Autowired
List<Service> myServices;
public void processServices(){
    boolean completed = false;
    Iterator<Service> myServicesIter = myServices.iterator();
    while(myServicesIter.hasNext() && !completed){
        Service service = myServicesIter.next();
        completed = service.process();
    }
    if(!completed){
       throw Exception();
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe that looks even easier compare to saving the next class in my service. Thanks!